How to accelerate getting points within distance using two DataFrames?
I have two DataFrames (df and locations_df), and both have longitude and latitude values. I'm trying to find the df's points within 2 km of each row of locations_df.
I tried to vectorize the function, but the speed is still slow when locations_df is a big DataFrame (nrows>1000). Any idea how to accelerate?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def select_points_for_multiple_locations_vectorized(df, locations_df, radius_km):
    R = 6371  # Earth's radius in kilometers

    # Convert degrees to radians
    df_lat_rad = np.radians(df['latitude'].values)[:, np.newaxis]
    df_lon_rad = np.radians(df['longitude'].values)[:, np.newaxis]
    loc_lat_rad = np.radians(locations_df['lat'].values)
    loc_lon_rad = np.radians(locations_df['lon'].values)

    # Haversine formula (vectorized)
    dlat = df_lat_rad - loc_lat_rad
    dlon = df_lon_rad - loc_lon_rad
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(df_lat_rad) * np.cos(loc_lat_rad) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1-a))
    distances = R * c

    # Create a mask for points within the radius
    mask = distances <= radius_km

    # Get indices of True values in the mask
    indices = np.where(mask)

    result = pd.concat([df.iloc[indices[0]].reset_index(drop=True), locations_df.iloc[indices[1]].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

    return result

def random_lat_lon(n=1, lat_min=-10., lat_max=10., lon_min=-5., lon_max=5.):
    """
    this code produces an array with pairs lat, lon
    """
    lat = np.random.uniform(lat_min, lat_max, n)
    lon = np.random.uniform(lon_min, lon_max, n)

    return np.array(tuple(zip(lat, lon)))

df = pd.DataFrame(random_lat_lon(n=10000000), columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])
locations_df = pd.DataFrame(random_lat_lon(n=20), columns=['lat', 'lon'])

result = select_points_for_multiple_locations_vectorized(df, locations_df, radius_km=2)


Does +/-5 deg latitude in your example data describe your spatial extent or are you actually dealing with a smaller / larger / much larger areas?

@margusl Actually, both data are global.

You need to use a spatial index to make this fast...
You can accomplish that like this:

convert your locations_df to a GeoDataFrame with polygons the size of your search distance by buffering them with this distance. As you don't seem to be working in a projected crs, check out this post how to do this: buffer circle WGS84.
determine which points intersect the buffered locations with a spatial join: geopandas.sjoin: result = df.sjoin(locations_buffered_df). This will use a spatial index under the hood so this will be fast.

Performance comparison
I added some sample code with a quick performance test, and using a spatial index indeed scales a lot better than brute-forcing all combinations. The performance is a lot better (not linear anymore with the number of combinations) and memory usage is a fraction as well.

for 1 mio points with 300 locations: 2.46 s with spatial index versus 36 s for the current implementation, so ~ a factor 15 faster. This is the maximum number of combinations I can run without running out of memory for the current implementation.
for 10 mio points with 1000 locations: 17.7 s for the implementation using a spatial index. I cannot run this on my desktop, but as this needs a factor 10.000/300 = 33 more distance calculations than the first test, I guess this will take the current implementation ~1200 s (20 minutes). Hence, using a spatial index is here probably ~ a factor 70 faster.

If you want really accurate results
Note that the buffers created in step 1 are polygons approximating circles, so the distance check is often good enough for most uses, but it is not perfect. If you want/need the distance check to be "perfect", or if you need the distance from the closest location in your result anyway, you can use a two-step filter approach. Use a slightly larger buffer distance for the primary, spatial index filtering so you are sure to retain all points that might be within distance. Then calculate the "exact" distance for that result (a small subset of the original input) to do a second filtering, e.g. with the vectorized haversine function you already have.
The results of the spatial join will also contain a reference (the dataframe index) to the "locations" they are ~within distance of, so if needed/wanted you can do an extra optimization to only calculate the distance to the relevant location(s).
Sample code with performance comparison
from time import perf_counter

import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform


def select_points_for_multiple_locations_vectorized(df, locations_df, radius_km):
    R = 6371  # Earth's radius in kilometers

    # Convert degrees to radians
    df_lat_rad = np.radians(df['latitude'].values)[:, np.newaxis]
    df_lon_rad = np.radians(df['longitude'].values)[:, np.newaxis]
    loc_lat_rad = np.radians(locations_df['lat'].values)
    loc_lon_rad = np.radians(locations_df['lon'].values)

    # Haversine formula (vectorized)
    dlat = df_lat_rad - loc_lat_rad
    dlon = df_lon_rad - loc_lon_rad
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(df_lat_rad) * np.cos(loc_lat_rad) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1-a))
    distances = R * c

    # Create a mask for points within the radius
    mask = distances <= radius_km

    # Get indices of True values in the mask
    indices = np.where(mask)

    result = pd.concat([df.iloc[indices[0]].reset_index(drop=True), locations_df.iloc[indices[1]].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

    return result

def random_lat_lon(n=1, lat_min=-10., lat_max=10., lon_min=-5., lon_max=5.):
    """
    this code produces an array with pairs lat, lon
    """
    lat = np.random.uniform(lat_min, lat_max, n)
    lon = np.random.uniform(lon_min, lon_max, n)

    return np.array(tuple(zip(lat, lon)))


def geodesic_point_buffer(lat, lon, km):
    # Azimuthal equidistant projection
    aeqd_proj = CRS.from_proj4(
        f"+proj=aeqd +lat_0={lat} +lon_0={lon} +x_0=0 +y_0=0")
    tfmr = Transformer.from_proj(aeqd_proj, aeqd_proj.geodetic_crs)
    buf = Point(0, 0).buffer(km * 1000)  # distance in metres
    return transform(tfmr.transform, buf)

df = pd.DataFrame(random_lat_lon(n=1_000_000), columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])
locations_df = pd.DataFrame(random_lat_lon(n=300), columns=['lat', 'lon'])

# Current implementation
start = perf_counter()
result = select_points_for_multiple_locations_vectorized(df, locations_df, radius_km=2)
print(f"{len(result)=}")
print(f"Took {perf_counter() - start}")

# Implementation using a spatial index
start = perf_counter()
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude))
locations_buffer_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    locations_df,
    geometry=locations_df.apply(lambda row : geodesic_point_buffer(row.lat, row.lon, 2), axis=1),
)
result = gdf.sjoin(locations_buffer_gdf)
print(f"{len(result)=}")
print(f"Took {perf_counter() - start}")

Output:
len(result)=1598
Took 36.21813579997979
len(result)=1607
Took 2.4568299000384286


@zxdawn I added a code sample and a performance test...
